# Preserve colors while piping to tee

Tags: pipe, tee

```
ls -l --color=auto | tee output.log
```

Without pipe/tee it's colored. How can I make it so that it stays colored while using `tee` (can be colored only on the screen, I don't care about colors in logs).

Comment: [Already asked on Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10823/where-do-my-ansi-escape-codes-go-when-i-pipe-to-another-process-can-i-keep-them).

Comment: A possible solution: `script -efq -c "ls --color=auto" >(cat) | tee outpu.log`

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Simply insert `unbuffer` before any command to make it think it is writing to an interactive output even if it is actually piping into another executable.  This will preserve color in the case of `ls`.

For example

```
unbuffer ls -l --color=auto | tee output.log
```

If you don't already have it installed, on Ubuntu and other Debian-ish Linux distributions you can install `unbuffer` by doing.

```
sudo apt-get install expect-dev
```

Comment: Another solution, which does not require installing anything, is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515208/can-colorized-output-be-captured-via-shell-redirect

Comment: This causes the resulting file to contain color codes (of course); is there any way to then *print* the file in a way that makes use of the color codes and properly displays the colors in the terminal?

Comment: Ugh, that makes password entries show your password in cleartext!

Comment: @Tgr That solution didn't work for me on OS X trying to get the raw colored output of `xcodebuild`— instead I got chopped-up lines with no color.  `unbuffer xcodebuild | less -R` worked flawlessly, however.

Comment: Ugh, unbuffer tries to install `expect libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-intel1 libdrm-nouveau2 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm2 libfontenc1 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libice6 libllvm4.0 libpciaccess0 libsm6 libtcl8.6 libtk8.6 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 libx11-6 libx11-data libx11-xcb1 libxau6 libxaw7 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-sync1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxdamage1 libxdmcp6 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxft2 libxi6 libxinerama1...`. Is there an option without the ridiculous 186 MB of dependencies?

Comment: @FakeName That's relative. For me, installing expect-devel (CentOS) has a download size of 2.2 MB and an installed size of 5 MB with only 2 deps (expect and tcl). But I already had the other deps! Anyway, you could try **tgr**'s suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515208/can-colorized-output-be-captured-via-shell-redirect

Comment: You don't need the `expect-dev` package. `expect` is enough.

Comment: The [cleanest solution](https://superuser.com/a/1434381/1183493) in this thread with a [bonus function](https://superuser.com/a/1641398/1183493).

Comment: @eamonn-obrien-strain When I insert `unbuffer` before `exec`, : `unbuffer exec > > (tee $LOG_FILE) 2>&1;`, I'm getting error: `couldn't execute "exec": no such file or directory while executing "spawn -noecho exec" ("eval" body line 1) invoked from within`

`"eval [list spawn -noecho] $argv" invoked from within "if {[string compare [lindex $argv 0] "-p"] == 0}`

`{ # pipeline set stty_init "-echo" eval [list spawn -noecho] [lrange $argv 1 end] | clo..." (file "/usr/bin/unbuffer" line 13)`. How do I solve this please. Thank you.

Comment: @eamonn-obrien-strain My question on AskUbuntu: `https://askubuntu.com/q/1344347/928088`. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

Use the ls option `--color=always`

`--color=auto` will not color output to a pipeline - for obvious reasons.

The `ls` man page says the following:

> With --color=auto,  color  codes  are output only if standard output is connected to a terminal (tty).

Comment: OK. That explains it. But can I still somehow see the colors on the screen? (It's a TTY after all). I don't mind NOT having them in the logfile, but I surely want them on my screen.

Comment: I think I made myself not clear enough. `ls -l` was just an example. I have a completely different command (heroku logs) that strips colors when piped to `tee`. And I want to "fix/change" tee/pipe, not the command I'm executing.

Comment: @Pawel, you can't easily fix it in tee/pipe as tee/pipe are not stripping these color codes. The problem is that the initial command sees it is not writing to the terminal. You need a [pseudo-terminal](http://linux.about.com/od/ttl_howto/a/hwtttl07t02.htm) that acts like a pipe but which commands see as a terminal.

Comment: Hm... fair enough. I guess I just need to accept that it's how it is.

Comment: @PawełGościcki have a look at /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/helpers/log_displayer.rb:20 and remove the condition that checks if you're on a terminal!

Comment: @PawełGościcki this answer only fixes the problem for `ls`. See my answer that fixes the problem for all programs, including heroku logs.

Comment: grep also has this option

Answer (score 16):

I'll expand the `script` solution given in the comment of the accepted answer.
Using `script` may be useful in case you can't or don't want to install the *expect* package that contains the `unbuffer` command.

**Print** `ls` output to stdout and file *with color codes*:

```
script -efq output.log -c "ls -l --color=auto"
```

where (`man script`):

> ```
>   -e, --return
>          Return the exit code of the child process.  Uses the same
>          format as bash termination on signal termination exit code is 128+n.
>   -f, --flush
>          Flush output after each write.  This is nice for telecooperation:
>         one person does `mkfifo foo; script -f foo', and another can 
>         supervise real-time what is being done using `cat foo'.
>   -q, --quiet
>          Be quiet (do not write start and done messages to either 
>          standard output or the typescript file).
> ```

**View** the output file with colors:

```
less -r output.log
```

Comment: @NoelMaersk Thanks. I incorporated the parameter explanations in the answer.

Comment: Perfect alternative for `unbuffer` thank you!

Comment: Clean! I turned it into a function with usage `output file command`. SO doesn't support this much code in a comment so I put it [here](https://superuser.com/a/1641398/1183493).

Comment: Look my answer for a more general approach. The script just forward the input to stdout instead of a file. Then it can be used for piping to a command directly

Answer (score 5):

`script -efq -c "ls --color=auto" >(cat) | tee output.log`

For convenience I created this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
script -efq -c "$*" >(cat)
```

call it say `unbuff` and then

```
unbuff ls --color=auto | tee output.log
```

Comment: Excellent! I came up with a solution but it required writing to a temp file and `cat`ing it back out (need to pipe into grep). The `>(cat)` saves that whole workaround. The version of `script` on my machine only takes `[-adkpqr]` args but this little function ended up working great:

`unbuff () { script -q >(cat) $* >/dev/null ; }`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function based off [this clean answer](https://superuser.com/a/1434381/1183493) that I couldn't fit in the comments.

```sh
output()
{
    output_file=$1
    shift
    command=$@
   
    script -efq $output_file -c "$command"
    less $output_file
}
```

Usage

```sh
output file command
```

Comment: on Darwin, "/usr/bin/script file command" works, no option needed.

Answer (score 1):

```shell
$ pipe-with-color(){ script -efq -O /dev/null -c "$@";}
$ pipe-with-color "git log origin/trunk.. --format='%Cred%h%Creset␟%C(cyan)%an%Creset␟%H␟%Cblue%f%Creset'" | git name-rev --annotate-stdin --always --name-only | column -t -s'␟'
```

[upper cmd GIF demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbkMk.gif)

pipe output and keep colors, but do not make a temp file(write the log out to `/dev/null` by `-O` option).

The upper example shows how it can be used: first, pipe the `git log ...` colored output to `git name-rev` to make it human readable(prev cmds output color keeps), then pipe again to indent for readability, the final result also keeps the `git log ...` output color.