# Keep color in less after make and pipe

Tags: linux, bash, zsh, make, less

I would like to keep color in less command after using "make 2>&1" to compile some program. There are similar topics with "grep" and "ls" commands but solutions do not work with this command.

For instance,

```
make 2>&1 | less -R
```

does not work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 16):

The simplest solution is:

```
unbuffer make |& less -r
```

This is based on the answer to [Preserve colors while piping to tee](https://superuser.com/questions/352697/preserve-colors-while-piping-to-tee/751809#751809)

I had to "sudo apt-get install expect" to get the unbuffer command installed.

Note that the "-r" option for less tells it to display ANSI color codes, while using |& pipes in both STDOUT and STDERR.

Comment: Thanks for this.  It works well for me.  Note though that if you want to restrict this to strictly ANSI escapes, you use `less -R` rather than `less -r`.  I had to look up what `|&` does.  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35384999/what-does-mean-in-bash)

Answer (score 6):

I think that you need to pass special parameters to gcc for this. Try this and let me know if it works:

```
export CXXFLAGS="-fdiagnostics-color"
#or
export CFLAGS="-fdiagnostics-color"
make 2>&1 | less -R
```

Comment: This is a first step to a solution. The makefile contains gcc command and the option "-fdiagnostics-color" is necessary to keep color after gcc and pipe. Nevertheless, color is not kept after make and pipe. Even if I use a simple Makefile with only one "gcc" command inside and nothing else.

Comment: OK I understand the problem. Your solution works partially. Your CFLAGS can be overriden by any makefile. What I would like is to use a shell alias in the makefile. alias g++="g++ -fdiagnostics-color=always" is not enough or to know a cleaner solution.

Comment: A partial solution is to use make -e which keep variables taken from the environment precedence over variables from makefiles. It is not convenient in my case.

Comment: Did you try lowercase option `-r` for `less`?

Comment: @fylou Why is the alias not a good enough solution for you? It looks like anything else will be a worse hack then this.

Comment: less -r doesn't not work.Aliases are not taken into account in the makefile. It would be ok for me if I could change this behaviour.

Comment: Assume that make output is colorized when not piped, on other commands (grep, ls, etcl) you add --colour=always (vs default auto). Make doesn't have this option so ?